# O que são StaticResources e DynamicResources no WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, uwp

Quando uso *resources* no WPF, posso especificá-las tanto como `StaticResource`, como `DyanamicResource`. Porém, na maioria das vezes só uma funciona, e a outra iniciaria uma exceção.

Partindo deste ponto, tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

- O que é uma `StaticResource` e o que é uma `DynamicResource`?
- Quando devo usar cada uma?
- Por que o UWP não permite usar `DynamicResources`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StaticResource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0) é carregado logo na carga do XAML e não é mais modificado. Ele é preferido pois dá mais performance. Todo o mecanismo do WPF sabe que não precisa ficar monitorando ele.

[DynamicResource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dynamicresource-markup-extension?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0) é uma expressão (é como uma variável) que indica o que é o recurso, então tem a flexibilidade de mudar em tempo de execução qual é o recurso utilizado. Sua carga efetivamente ocorre só quando o recurso precisa ser usado, por isso pode até mesmo ser um recurso a ser criado. Basta trocar o que resultará a expressão que o recurso pode ser outro. Uma mudança disparará mudanças em toda a árvore de objetos da tela.

Na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml-resources-define?view=netdesktop-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) da Microsoft tem uma lista de cenários em que ele podem ser usados.

| Feature | Static | Dynamic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Conhecimento sobre os recursos | Tempo de desenvolvimento | Tempo de execução |
| Manipulação do ResourceDicitionary | Não | Sim |
| Referência não conhecida ainda | Não | Sim |
| Temas e controles personalizados | Recursos internos | Referências externas |
| Recursos compartilhados | Sim | Não |
| Grande quantidade de dependências | Sim | Não |
| Recursos muito grandes | Não | Sim |
| Valores provindos externamente | Não | Sim |
| Colocação na árvore de objetos | Posição fixa | Qualquer lugar |

Não tenho uma informação conclusiva, mas parece que não há recursos dinâmicos no UWP porque aprenderam que traz mais problema que benefícios. [Isso pode ser útil](http://amadeusw.com/xaml/uwp-cheat-sheet). E usei que é possível alguma mudança, e parece que andaram melhorando algumas coisas, mas ainda não tome como verdade.