# Diferença entre os usos StaticResource e ThemeResource UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Para se declarar um TextBlock com style HeaderTextBlockStyle pode se usar essas duas formas onde o resultado é o mesmo:

```
<TextBlock Text="Olá, Mundo!" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
<TextBlock Text="Olá, Mundo!" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
```

Existe alguma diferença entre esses dois? E qual situação é mais adequado para usar o StaticResource e o ThemeResource?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173387/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo [a documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension):

(Texto retirado da documentação)

A **ThemeResource** é uma técnica para obtenção de valores referentes a um atributo XAML definidos em outro lugar em um dicionário de recursos XAML. Essa extensão de marcação tem a mesma finalidade básica que a extensão de marcação **StaticResource**.

*A diferença de comportamento em relação à extensão de marcação **{StaticResource}** é que uma referência **ThemeResource** pode usar dinamicamente diferentes dicionários como o local de pesquisa principal, dependendo do tema atualmente utilizado pelo sistema.*

*Quando e como usar {ThemeResource} em vez de {StaticResource}?*

*As regras pelas quais **ThemeResource** é resolvido para um item em um dicionário de recursos costumam ser as mesmas de StaticResource. Uma pesquisa de ThemeResource pode ser estendida para os arquivos do ResourceDictionary que são referenciados em uma coleção de ThemeDictionaries, mas um StaticResource também pode fazer isso. `A diferença é que um ThemeResource pode ser reavaliado no tempo de execução e um StaticResource não.`*

Referências:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/staticresource-markup-extension
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension